# how to use CURL commands in PYTHON

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I want to send this command in a python program. How can I do this? I do not need to print any response.

```
curl -k -X PUT 'http://10.210.12.158:10065/iot/put_bulb/true?id=4'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python/92395#92395

Comment: For HTTP you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. It's very versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os`:

```
from os import system
system("curl -k -X PUT 'http://10.210.12.158:10065/iot/put_bulb/true?id=4'")
```

Using `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.Popen("curl -k -X PUT 'http://10.210.12.158:10065/iot/put_bulb/true?id=4'", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shell](https://shell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#quickstart) module to run such commands neatly:

```py
>>> from shell import shell
>>> curl = shell("curl -k -X PUT 'http://10.210.12.158:10065/iot/put_bulb/true?id=4'")
>>> curl.output()
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) module for making such http requests from Python.

Comment: Python has 3 different modules that allow comnand execution built-in. Why an other external one?